# Laravel eloquent returns different type of result on local and live

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

On my localhost laravel eloquent returns object while on live server it returns an array.

Why is this happening? is there any setting I need to update?

```
$parent_user = User::where('email', $organiser->email)->first();
```

Laravel v5.2

Comment: Make sue the same php modules in your local machine you have it on live machine

Comment: can you elaborate on that? what modules should I be looking for here?